# sql complix select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've the following table with this data

```
UserID RegistreType RegistreTime            
2549    1           2015-09-01 07:37:38.000
2549    1           2015-09-02 07:40:32.000
2549    1           2015-09-03 07:36:02.000
2549    2           2015-09-03 17:37:17.000
2549    1           2015-09-04 12:57:49.000
2549    2           2015-09-05 01:50:17.000
2549    1           2015-09-05 17:35:41.000
2549    2           2015-09-06 03:22:54.000
2549    2           2015-09-07 08:22:54.000
```

and its required from me to do an sql statement to select data as following

```
UserID          IN                          OUT
2549            2015-09-01 07:37:38.000     -
2549            2015-09-02 07:40:32.000     -
2549            2015-09-03 07:36:02.000     2015-09-03 17:37:17.000
2549            2015-09-04 12:57:49.000     2015-09-05 01:50:17.000
2549            2015-09-05 17:35:41.000     2015-09-06 03:22:54.000
2549            -                           2015-09-07 08:22:54.000
```

as you can see the `RegistreType` when it equals 1 the its `IN` 
and if there is no `OUT` in the same day then I should get the out of the second day but only IF its before the `IN`

I hope you get more idea in the output table
How I can do this is SQL???

Comment: Do you really need the query to run on both MySQL and MS SQL Server? (Some product specific SQL may be needed...)

Comment: @jarlh actuality I'm working on sql server, but I think the sql statement are similar for both mysql and mssql, so I hope I get an answer for this

Comment: There can be at most one IN and one OUT per day? Or more?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner more, this table shows users finger print, so it can be the user did more than on IN or OUT in the same day

Comment: And then what? Show all INs with their next OUT in that day? But then, when I have IN1, IN2, OUT1, OUT2, then OUT1 is the next for both IN1 and IN2. Or would that not be possible? Would there always be an OUT before a new IN on the same day for the same user?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Actually, I think the OP's explanation covers that case.

Comment: do you want `min(RegistreTime)` for a user on a given day as `IN` and `max(RegistreTime)` as `out`

Comment: @Mini yes, and if there is no OUT of the same day, then I should consider the OUT of the next day. but in the same time it should be before the IN

Comment: @Strawberry can you explain more?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the sae should be like, if I came to work and I register 'IN' at 9PM then after finish I registered 'OUT' on 1 AM of the second day. then I need this two records of different days appears in the same line

Comment: @Strawberry and Khalil Rumman: Yes, sorry, thank you, I got confused somehow. I've provided some answers. Hope they work. Nothing for MySQL though, because mySQL doesn't feature analytic functions. In MySQL one might use subqueries or SQL variables somehow to get to the desired results.

Comment: @Khalil Rumman you should at least TRY to write the query before asking the question, this is not a site to just ask others to do your work for you

Comment: @Used_By_Already I've tried many times, but I didn't make it, thanks for your support, and help. if you don't know how to help don't stand as a wall

Comment: oh! ha ha. I do know how to help. The facts are you are supposed to demonstrate that you have tried to write the query by showing us your work. This is a long standing convention of this help site. Otherwise it is abused as a 'do this work for me (for nothing)' site - and you never learn to stand on your own.

Comment: @Khalil Rumman: You should not be offended when someone requests to see some effort on your site. This is how this site works; you show your query to demonstrate how far you got and where you are stuck. Then we can comment on your aproach, correct minor errors or show alternatives. On the other hand, however, this query is quite difficult to write, so I imagine you tried this and that and got nothing that came close enough to show here. But then simply say so instead of accusing someone of not wanting to help :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ok thank you for the advice :) but I've been on this problem since 2 weeks, and I'm a web developer but its the first time I work in such complicated SQL statements and my knowledge is small in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEAD` to get the next record. (Not available in MySQL!) Then show all IN records and look whether the found next record is OUT in order to either show the OUT time or not.

Then you also need the OUT records without an IN. So do the same for OUT records with `LAG` (again not available in MySQL) and only use those lacking a previous IN.

Then glue the two results together with UNION ALL.

```
select * from
(
  select 
    userid,
    this_time as in_time,
    case when next_type = 2 then next_time end as out_time
  from
  (
    select 
      userid, 
      registretime as this_time,
      registretype as this_type,
      lead(registretime) over (partition by userid order by registretime) as next_time,
      lead(registretype) over (partition by userid order by registretime) as next_type
    from mytable
  ) in_and_next
  where this_type = 1
  union all
  select 
    userid,
    null as in_time,
    this_time as out_time
  from
  (
    select 
      userid, 
      registretime as this_time,
      registretype as this_type,
      lag(registretime) over (partition by userid order by registretime) as prev_time,
      lag(registretype) over (partition by userid order by registretime) as prev_type
    from mytable
  ) in_and_next
  where this_type = 2
  and (prev_type = 2 or prev_type is null)
) x
order by userid, coalesce(in_time, out_time);
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b119/9.

Here is my approach to do that all in one query without UNION ALL:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    userid,
    case when this_type = 1 then this_time end as in_time,
    case 
      when this_type = 1 and next_type = 2 then next_time 
      when this_type = 2 and (prev_type = 2 or prev_type is null) then this_time
    end as out_time
  from
  (
    select 
      userid, 
      registretime as this_time,
      registretype as this_type,
      lead(registretime) over (partition by userid order by registretime) as next_time,
      lead(registretype) over (partition by userid order by registretime) as next_type,
      lag(registretime) over (partition by userid order by registretime) as prev_time,
      lag(registretype) over (partition by userid order by registretime) as prev_type
    from mytable reg_in
  ) x
  where this_type = 1 -- all IN, no matter whether next record is OUT
  or (this_type = 2 and (prev_type = 2 or prev_type is null)) -- OUT without previous IN
) y
order by userid, coalesce(in_time, out_time);
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b119/13.

Comment: @Thorsten: Your effort is appreciable

Answer (score 1):

After providing my first answer, I've come up with a much simpler approach using `ROW_NUMBER` (not available in MySQL): Number each user's entries, so you can combine each record with its next. Then full outer join, so as to get IN-OUT pairs:

```
with numbered as
(
  select 
    userid, 
    registretime,
    registretype,
    row_number() over (partition by userid order by registretime) num
  from mytable      
)
select
  coalesce(n1.userid, n2.userid) as userid,
  n1.registretime,
  n2.registretime
from numbered n1
full outer join numbered n2
  on n2.userid = n1.userid
  and n2.num = n1.num + 1
  and n1.registretype = 1
  and n2.registretype = 2
where (n1.registretype = 1 or n2.registretype = 2)
order by coalesce(n1.registretime, n2.registretime);
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b119/16.

Comment: thank you its good, but it only has one issue if you can fix it. the records are duplicated, I mean in '2015-09-04' I get the row twice, once with the completed 'IN' 'OUT' and once only with 'IN'

Comment: Sure, sorry, I didn't think it through. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you also this one worked, thanks for the help :)